# Django tags for templates in Eclipse

Tags: django, eclipse, django-templates, tags

I'm wondering if is it possible to have autocompletion, autoformatting, and those beautiful things working in Eclipse IDE for Django based templates.

Mainly for these things:  `{% ... %} {{ ... }}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: The current recommended way is by using LiClipse. See answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20837924/110451 for details

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this page for Django Eclipse plugin: http://eclipse.kacprzak.org/

Comment: installed this, but it doesn't work. It doesn't show up in poperties and in editors.

Comment: templates cannot be imported or added from @man2xxl 's asnwer.

Answer (score 2):

I have started creating my own template in Windows > Preferences > Editors > HTML > Templates, for example for  the `{% code %}` and `{% endcomment %}` tag. Of course, this is not exactly what you want, because it is not dynamically, and that is exactly where it would help most.

Comment: Any thoughts of releaseing that (or building something worth releaseing from it, if you think it's to tiny yet) ?

Answer (score 2):

By default PyDev has "Templates" which makes this very easy. I created templates for all the Django template tags and shared them on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ipoots/django-eclipse-templates). Just download them and import it in Eclipse.

Comment: Strange - I don't see a change to my templates after importing your definitions. How can I tell something changed?

Comment: Are you importing at Window > Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Templates? After this when you are working on *.html page you can type CTRL+Space and get a list of Django templates to use. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The link is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know of anything.  *A priori*, it sounds possible that a project might get the `{% ... %}` working properly, but the `{{ ... }}` could be quite a stretch.  Consider that the django templates don't know anything about code that will be filling them in, so there's no real way to look at headers or a symbol table and guess that when you start typing `fo` that `foobar` might be a valid variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the PyDev 2.0 has integration with Django Templates Editor that works with Aptana Studio 3 from 2010-08-18. This may be a little dated. I'm trying to get the same thing done today. There are instructions from [Fabio Zadrozny](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2010/08/django-templates-editor.html)