# Tips for configuring PyDev/Eclipse for optimal Django template editing (sans Aptana)?

Tags: django, eclipse, django-templates, pydev

What I'm looking for is:

- Full syntax highlighting including of {% Django template keywords %}
  and {{ Django template expressions }}
- Additional editing conveniences specific to Django templates, analogous to the many features the PyDev editor has for .py source (e.g. the Command-1 quick fix for errors/warnings, PEP8 checking, and much more)
- Suppression of extraneous warnings resulting form template code breaking normal HTML syntax, e.g. "Invalid text" warning for Django template code and "Resource not found" warning when referring to {{ STATIC_URL}}xyz.js etc.

I know that the Aptana Studio version of Eclipse has a Django specific template editor. This question is specifically for normal Eclipse/Pydev sans Aptana Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Edit:

The current recommended way would be using LiClipse. See aswer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20837924/110451

Another option is using http://eclipse.kacprzak.org (or Aptana Studio 3, although it has a really old PyDev version bundled at this time).

Comment: I don't want to mess with my existing PyDev setup -- and it seems you need to uninstall PyDev to install Aptana. Also I've seen a number of references to Aptana being overweight and clunky. But yes, perhaps it's time I took a proper look for myself.

Comment: Well, if you feel it's not suited, please report that and if possible how you think it can be improved for you... it's being actively developed and the team is working especially on performance and fixing usability bugs at the moment, so, if you have a problem with it, it'd be a good time to report it and have that fixed :)

Comment: And just to complete, yes, as it's a superset which already includes PyDev, you have to remove PyDev before, although I'd recommend getting the Aptana Studio 3 standalone and pointing it to your existing workspace to test it -- and saving the .metadata of your workspace before, so, it's easy to go back to the previous state.

Comment: Re: the Django Editor plug-in link you noted in your answer -- thanks for that -- I've just tried installing it without success. (There is a "Django Template Editor" that installs without error but doesn't seem to do anything, i.e. no new choice of editor appears; and there's a "Django Editor" that throws various "artifact not found" errors on install.)

Comment: Re: Aptana, yes, I'd like to give it a try sooner or later, especially if it's the only real solution to my question here. Can I download and intall the standalone version without affecting my current Eclipse 3.8/PyDev installation?

Comment: Yes, you can download and use the standalone without affecting your current installation (as a safeguard, just backup the .metadata in your workspace to restore it if needed).

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add to the above answer as people are complaining about not seeing any difference in their editors.

Merely installing Django Editor Plugin won't make any difference. You have to explicitly associate the editor to edit all `.html` files.

You can link `.html` files to use Django Editor by going to:

> Windows Menu > Preferences > General > Editor > File Associations

Once you do that, Django Editor plugin takes care of code highlighting and auto completion of templates.

For completeness sake, the installation process can be found [here](http://eclipse.kacprzak.org/).