# Is there an Eclipse html editor suitable for Django (an Eclipse plugin)?

Tags: html, django, eclipse, editor

I'm using Django within Eclipse. I edit my templates (the html pages) with Eclipse web page editor (an Eclipse plugin in "Web, XML and Java EE development").

The web page editor obviously doesn't do syntax highlighting and autocompletions to anything which isn't plain html (like `{% block title %}` or `{{ user.username }}`).

Is there an eclipse html editor which does that?

**EDIT:** I was trying to install http://eclipse.kacprzak.org/ but it refuses to be installed ("An error occurred while collecting items to be installed"). I'm not the only one who cannot install the above plugin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670643/django-tags-for-templates-in-eclipse

Comment: you also might want to take a look at pydev and/or aptana.

Comment: @something: In the question you are linking to they propose kacprzak, which doesn't work anymore. I've updated my question to mention this.

Comment: @ashwoods: Thanks, but I'm using pydev already and it doesn't include a Django-friendly html editor.

Answer (score 0):

PyDev includes a [templates editor](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2010/08/django-templates-editor.html) that handles all the {} stuff, but you have to use the nightly PyDev build and Aptana studio as opposed to Eclipse.

I don't really like Aptana, it's a little *too* helpful, and found that the template syntax highlighting wasn't all that useful. They're not supposed to get terribly complex anyway. But some people like it, so there's one suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What error did you get while installing? Were you able to finally install it? I've just got it installed. I noted that if I selected the "Django Templates Editor", the installation failed. But if I select only the "Django Editor", the installation goes through.

And yes, I was able to start editing my .html files from eclipse! Though am a novice 0.001 when it comes to HTML skills. Some dreamweaver thing would really be helpful for our type of people.